# Keras - LSTM model with two text column

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm trying to make LSTM model which reads two related text columns and gives label as output.

Column names are 'premise' and 'hypothesis', And I need to predict if hypothesis fits to premise. (label is 0, 1, 2)

How can I make LSTM model with two column? below is my code I tried.

plus, I encoded train_y using one hot encoding

```
texts = pd.concat([train_df["premise"], train_df["hypothesis"]])
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)

premise = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_df["premise"])
hypothesis = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_df["hypothesis"])
sentences = premise + hypothesis
max_len = max([len(s) for s in sentences])

premise = [pad_words(s, max_len) for s in premise]
hypothesis = [pad_words(s, max_len) for s in hypothesis]
train_x = np.stack((premise, hypothesis), axis=-1) # shape: (12120, 196, 2)

# making model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1, 128))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.4, recurrent_dropout=0.4))
model.add(Dense(3, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(
    loss="categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer="adam",
    metrics=["acc"]
)
model.summary()

#expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (32, 196, 2, 128)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_data=(val_x, val_y))
```

Comment: Check early fusion and late fusion in deep learning, like you could have two separate inputs (one for each column) followed by LSTM layers then you merge the features and apply your classification layer.